# kendoDropDownList conflicts with jquery.validate.js

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Trying to use Kendo UI with native MVC validation, but if I simply include **jquery.validate.js** the Kendo UI DropDownList does not work correctly.  it will drop down, but I cannot select anything anymore.  Any workarounds or something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors? You can also try latest version of jquery.validate.js. It gets updated often.

Comment: it was an older version of validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Kendo DropDownListFor, which will work with your model's validation attributes as you are probably expecting.